# Lebesgue Measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, probability-limit-theorems

Hi guys I got a doubt about how to interpret the following:

> Given measurable space $(\Omega, \Im ) \hspace{.1cm} \text{and} \hspace{.1cm}(\mathbb{P}_n)_{n\geq0 }$ succession of probability measures defined on $(\Omega, \Im) $ and $\forall \hspace{.1cm} A \in\Im:$ $\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_{n}\mathbb{P}_n(A)$

*Now if $\hspace{.01cm}$ $\varphi$ is an integrable function with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ $\hspace{.01cm}$, then $\hspace{.01cm}$ $\varphi$ is an integrable function with respect to $\mathbb{P}_n$*

***I can barely understand why this happens, but i get confused why the reciprocal it's not true:***

*If $\hspace{.01cm}$ $\varphi$ is an integrable function with respect to $\mathbb{P}_n$, $\hspace{.01cm}$ then$\hspace{.01cm}$ $\varphi$ is an integrable function with respect to $\mathbb{P}$*

Why this is false?

---

Comment: So $\mathbb{E}(\varphi)= \int_{\Omega } \varphi(\omega) d\mathbb{P}_n(\omega)$ exists but could be that $\mathbb{P}_n$ grows so fast that $\mathbb{E}(\varphi)= \int_{\Omega } \varphi(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ may not exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the failure of the converse, consider $a_n=2^{-(n+1)}$ and $\mathbb{P}_n$ concentrated on the number $3^n$ with $\varphi(x)=x$.

Comment: But what if the $a_n=1$?

Comment: @AbrahamBerrielRangel I assume that $\mathbb{P}$ itself should be a probability measure considering the choice of notation, but if you set $a_n=1$ anyway, it doesn't change anything in my example.